# Prove The Identity of Author Using GPG On Demand

Tags: gnupg, identity

Given a situation where I want to be anonymous by default, how can I use GPG to prove that I'm the original author once, on-demand, and for a specific user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a private/public keypair in GPG.  Then, use GPG to sign the document using the private key, and append the signature and the public key to the document.

When it comes time to prove you are the author, prove that you are in possession of the private key by using it to sign something else.

Related: [How to Prove you created Intellectual Property (IP) using a Notary](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/220247/how-to-prove-you-created-intellectual-property-ip-using-a-notary)

Comment: is there a command?

Comment: @schroeder Yes.  https://linux.die.net/man/1/gpg

Comment: lol, I mean is there a command to do all these things? Creating new keys that are meant to be "anonymous", signing, and appending the key?

Comment: Isn't there a way to prove it to a specific user without the risk of exposing it to everyone?

Comment: @schroeder it's just a public/private keypair.  The keys are 'anonymous' in that the public key is not tied to any identity (as would be the case if the public key is part of a certificate).  The commands to create the key pair, sign the document using the private key, and verify the signature using the public key are in the man page that I linked.

Comment: @SRezaS Yes, you prove to a specific user that you are the author, without exposing this to everyone, by proving to just that user that you are the in possession of the private key.

Comment: See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/270054/whats-the-shortest-message-you-need-to-claim-ownership-of-another-message for a similar question, with a similar solution.